# MVC WebGrid - How to programatically get the current page, sort column etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

How can I programatically (in javascript) get the current page number, last sort column and sort direction of the ASP.NET MVC WebGrid?

Is it possible to update the arguments before it calls the `$("#grid").load()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution was to use jQuery to retrieve:
- the "href" attribute from the first column header to get the page number and 
- the "href" attribute from the "next page number" to get the sort column and sort directions.

```
function reloadGrid(form) {
    var grid = form._grid ? form._grid.value : "grid";
    var args = {};
    updateQueryParams(args, grid + " th a");
    args.sort = "";
    args.sortdir = "";
    updateQueryParams(args, grid + " tfoot a");
    args.page = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        var el = form.elements[i];
        if (el.type == "text" || el.type == "select" || (el.type == "radio" && el.checked))
            args[el.name] = el.value;
        else if (el.type == "checkbox")
            args[el.name] = el.checked;
    }

    //get controller name
    var s = $("#grid th a")[0].onclick.toString();
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("/"));
    var controller = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("?"));

    var queryString = "";
    for (var key in args)
        queryString += "&" + key + "=" + escape(args[key]);

    var url = controller + "?" + queryString.substring(1);
    $("#" + grid).load(url + " #" + grid);
}


function updateQueryParams(args, path) {
    var links = $("#" + path);
    if (links.length == 0)
        return;

    var s = links[0].onclick.toString();
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("?") + 1);
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" #"));

    var a = /\+/g;  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    var r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
    var d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); };
    var q = s;

    while (e = r.exec(q))
        args[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
}
```