# How do you get to the underlying data in an MVC3 WebGrid using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, select, webgrid

I have a simple MVC WebGrid.  When a user clicks on a row, I'd like to do something based on the row he clicked.  Its pretty simple in jqGrid and even using jquery templates, but I'd like to get it right using the MVC WebGrid.

I have the following:

```
<h2>OrderList</h2>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 20, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid_Orders");
    grid.Bind(Model.Orders, rowCount: Model.TotalOrders, autoSortAndPage: true);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid_Orders" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName: "OrderNo", header: "Order No"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "TotalAmountDisplay", header: "Amount", format:@<div style="text-align:right"> R @item.TotalAmountDisplay</div>, canSort: false)
    ));
}
```

and the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid_Orders").delegate("tbody tr", "hover", function () {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).toggleClass("datahighlight");
    });

    $("#grid_Orders").delegate("tbody tr", "click", function () {
        //How do I get the underlying data in this row???
    });

});
```

Comment: I've managed to get the OrderNo out, but I'm sure this is not the right way of doing it       

$("#grid_Orders").delegate("tbody tr", "click", function () {
        alert($(this).children(':first-child').html());
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to use jQuery in order to access each row's html data - there is no rich programming model against it that Im aware of (the beauty of MVC at times as well ha)

The same scenario applies here:
[MVC WebGrid - How to programatically get the current page, sort column etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344668/mvc-webgrid-how-to-programatically-get-the-current-page-sort-column-etc)

Comment: Hopefully the Template/Databinding team gets some input into this helper in the near future

Comment: if you use json and bind to a grid you have access to your source data. not sure if the webgrid supports this but teleriks does - which is a 100x better grid imho and free.